# Where can I store tmp files in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony

I read that I can use app/cache or app/logs for tmp files, but it doesn't feel right because they are not gonna be removed unless I do it myself.

For example, I need to store a date in a file (I don't want to use a database for this), and I only need it to be there for 2 or 3 days.

What can I do?

Comment: Place it in a regular file into a tmp folder inside your bundle.
Then use a cron (if this days interval is fixed) for remove them

Comment: The Symfony directory layout changed in version 3.3. Now `/app` only contains config files, templates and web assets. Logs, temporary files, and the cache have been moved to `/var`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is's not a good practice to let the web server to write inside a bundle. You can do it but you'll have to deal with permissions and it introduces a security risk...

Why not using /tmp (on a UNIX server) that is regularly cleaned or your own tmp dir like /home/ChocoDeveloper/tmp with cron task to clean it ?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry this isn't an answer to the exact question being asked, but I'd suggest that there are better ways of achieving this without resorting to storing a date in a temporary file, even if you don't want to use the database.

Have you considered using Redis or Memcache? There are Symfony2 bundles for both of these that should make life a bit easier, although you'd need to ensure that both are installed and running on your server.

If you were to do this using Redis, for example, you could make use of the [EXPIRE](http://redis.io/commands/expire) command to specify how long you want the value (in this case your date) to exist. Here's the rough idea:

```
public function yourMethod()
{
    $date = $this->getDate();

    /* ... */
}

protected function getDate()
{
    /** @var $redis \Predis\Client */
    $redis = $this->container->get('snc_redis.default'); // TODO inject as a dependency

    $date = $redis->get('your_key');

    // Will be empty if requested after the key has expired.
    // Set a new date value in the key
    if (empty($date)) {
        $date = '2013-01-17 13:30:00'; // Not sure where you want to get this from
        $redis->set('your_key', $date);

        $secondsToLive = 259200; // 3 days
        $redis->expire('your_key', $secondsToLive);
    }

    return $date;
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the data will be kept in memory, which I don't want. I might end up not accessing the data at all, but I need it to be there for a few days just in case. I should have specified.

Comment: Offtopic: I usually avoid using the 'php' tag to avoid score whores who try to answer very specific or difficult symfony2 questions, without ever having used the framework. They won't give up, and if you don't accept an answer they even end up downvoting you. It's quite annoying. In this case, I was about to use the php tag, wasn't sure. Thanks either way.

Comment: Ok no worries. Yeah I know what you mean regarding the `php` tag, but I find it's always handy to have if there are code snippets as I posted above.